# Showing only a subset of values on an axis of a Pandas plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset containing the infection rate of the Mirai botnet per country. I would like to create a frequency distribution of the infection rate. In order to do so, i use the following lines:

```
inf ['Infection_Rate'] = inf.Infection_Rate.round(2)
x =inf['Infection_Rate'].value_counts()
x.plot( kind='bar')
```

Which gives me the following plot

[image: Plot]

My main issue with this plot is that every value is plotted on the x-axis of the plot. I would like to limit the labels on the x-axis. As the Infection Rate grossly varies between 0 - 1.5, I would like the x-axis to only display 6 values, for example 0, 0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Your xaxis isn't sorted, so leaving out some labels in between would render the plot useless (because you cannot know to which value an unlabeled bar corresponds). You may explain better what you're trying to achieve and also provide a [mcve], so people have a chance to answer this.